# Pivot table custom formula to keep most recent of duplicate value information

Tags: google-sheets, pivot

I'm working on a pivot table in sheets (google's version of excel). The database contains records of survey data where there are multiple entries for each person at different timepoints. I want this pivot table to filter the records so that it only shows the most recent data for each person. Does anyone know a custom formula I can write that would evaluate duplicate name values against the date of the entry so that the end result shows only the most recent data for each person?

I know I can filter for date, but there isn't any consistency with the dates and names in this database. The surveys are given out at sporadic times, so the dates are all different.

So I have rows of information that basically look like:

| Name | Date | Value | Timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Luna | 11/1/23 | 3 | Checkpoint 1 |
| Raz | 12/11/23 | 2 | Checkpoint 1 |
| Luna | 12/14/23 | 3 | Checkpoint 2 |
| Luna | 1/12/24 | 4 | Checkpoint 3 |
| Raz | 1/21/24 | 3 | Checkpoint 2 |

There are more data points in the database and records but this is the information I'm including in this one pivot table. The values are based on a scale of 1-5. What I'm looking for the pivot table to summarize is how many people have each value at the most recent point in time. So the pivot table will look like:

COUNTA of Value

| Value (1-5) | Checkpoint 1 | Checkpoint 2 | Checkpoint 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | 1 |  |
| 4 |  |  | 1 |
| 5 |  |  |  |

Comment: Please don't tag with Excel/VBA if you're using Google Sheets

Comment: What is the definition of `the most recent data for each person.`?

Comment: You could use `query` to analyse your data and create the pivot table; use dropdowns to select `user`, `start date` and `end date` as variables for the query; end date could be = Max(Date); lots of options for setting `start date`

Comment: Please attach example sheets. Google Sheet formulas always have some dependency to the structure of your data -- how they are spread across cells. Your example sheet can show that.

Comment: @Tedinoz The data I'm referring to includes rows where the data I'm looking at is Name, Date Survey Completed, subject value, and a corresponding number value between 1-5. So for example, on 1/1/24 Luna has Option 1 for [value], and on 2/1/24 Luna has Option 2 for [value]. So I want the pivot table to show the data for Luna for 2/1/24 as it is the most recent date, but not 1/1/24 or anything prior. The problem I'm facing is that the dates are sporadic. So for Luna it could be 1/1/24  and 2/1/24 but for Ted it could be 1/15/24 and 11/3/23. And I need the table to show data for both.

Comment: Please edit the question to include sample data and an example of the desired outcome.

Comment: Added sample data, let me know if that's clear. Thank you!

Comment: The “rules” relating to the outcome are vague and ambiguous and the expected outcome seems inconsistent with the sample data & comments. “So I want the pivot table to show the data for Luna for 2/1/24 as it is the most recent date, but not 1/1/24 or anything prior.” Yet checkpoint2/value3 must refer to Luna, and Checkpoint1/Value2 (Raz) is not included in the outcome.